# SQL Query optimization : Taking lots of time

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlperformance

I am having the following query used to retrieve a set of orders:

```
select count(distinct po.orderid) 
from PostOrders po, 
     ProcessedOrders pro 
where pro.state IN ('PENDING','COMPLETED') 
  and po.comp_code in (3,4) 
  and pro.orderid = po.orderid
```

The query returns a result of 4323, and does so fast enough.

But I have to put another condition such that it returns only if it is not present in another table DiscarderOrders for which I add an extra condition to the query:

```
select count(distinct po.orderid) 
from PostOrders po, 
     ProcessedOrders pro 
where pro.state IN ('PENDING','COMPLETED') 
  and po.comp_code in (3,4) 
  and pro.orderid = po.orderid 
  and po.orderid not in (select do.order_id from DiscardedOrders do)
```

The above query takes a lot of time and just keeps on running. Is there anything I can do to the query such that it executes fast? Or do I need to execute the first query first, and then filter based on the condition by shooting another query?

Comment: Please provide execution plans for both queries and table structures, on which columns do you have an index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to replace:

```
and po.orderid not in (select do.order_id from DiscardedOrders do)
```

by

```
and not exists (select 1 from DiscardedOrders do where do.order_id = po.orderid)
```

Answer (score 2):

try using `JOIN` than `NOT IN`

```
SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT po.orderid) TotalCount
FROM    PostOrders po
        INNER JOIN ProcessedOrders pro
            ON po.orderid = pro.orderid
        LEFT JOIN DiscardedOrders do
            ON po.orderid = do.orderid
WHERE   po.comp_code IN (3,4) AND
        pro.state IN ('PENDING','COMPLETED') AND
        do.orderid IS NULL
```

OR `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT po.orderid) TotalCount
FROM    PostOrders po
        INNER JOIN ProcessedOrders pro
            ON po.orderid = pro.orderid
WHERE   po.comp_code IN (3,4) AND
        pro.state IN ('PENDING','COMPLETED') AND
        NOT EXISTS
        (
            SELECT  1
            FROM    DiscardedOrders do
            WHERE   po.orderid = do.orderid
        )
```

Comment: You might want to add that a JOIN is not necessarily equivalent to a `NOT IN` condition e.g. if `DiscardedOrders` can contain the same `orderid` more than once (probably not the case here though)

Answer (score 0):

Same as distinct:

```
SELECT count(po.orderid) 
  FROM PostOrders po 
 WHERE po.comp_code IN (3,4) 
   AND EXISTS 
   (
   SELECT 1 FROM ProcessedOrders pro 
    WHERE pro.orderid = po.orderid
      AND pro.state IN ('PENDING','COMPLETED') 
   )
  ....
 /
```